# Java: How to get SubClasses in Provider in Dependency Injection

Tags: java

Given 3 classes: `FooA`, `FooB` and `FooC`, which are all subclasses of the abstract class `Foo`. However, all are using the same constructor with Dependency Injection, so I am using `javax.inject.Provider` to get fully injected instances of the subclasses.

```
Provider<FooA> fooAProvider
Provider<FooB> fooBProvider
Provider<FooC> fooCProvider
```

How can I sum the Providers up to become a `Provider<Foo> fooProvider`, while still being able to get instances of its subclass or is there another way to get rid of the multiple Provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a producer and qualifiers to distinguish resolved instances:

```
public class ProviderSuppliers {
    @Producer
    @Named("fooA")
    public static Provider<Foo> getFooA() {
        return //create Provider for FooA
    }
    @Producer
    @Named("fooB")
    public static Provider<Foo> getFooB() {
        return //create Provider for FooB
    }
    @Producer
    @Named("fooC")
    public static Provider<Foo> getFooC() {
        return //create Provider for FooC
    }
}
```

Then you can inject them using the qualifier:

```
@Inject
@Named("fooA")
Provider<FooA> fooAProvider

@Inject
@Named("fooB")
Provider<FooB> fooBProvider

//and so on
```

Now, on `Provider<Foo>`: this is a little problematic because you technically can't do this:

```
Provider<Foo> fooA = new Provider<FooA>(); //you can't assign like this.
```

However, you can still declare as below and still get it to work by injecting the expected instance (the qualifier takes care of that)

```
@Inject
@Named("fooA")
Provider<Foo> fooAProvider
```

This is practically bad as you're simply going around type safety. The better approach would be to just have the same type declared on producer and at injection point, which also helps with type safety where `Provider<FooX>` objects are actually used.